# Estou começando com html5

Tags: html5

Vocês sabem de alguns sites ou alguns assuntos sobre html5 para estudar, estou começando agora nessa área e tenho vontade de ter um conhecimento mais avançado em html5 para depois partir para uma linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 2):

Esse site aqui https://www.w3schools.com/ da W3C é um belo guia pra quem ta começando.Ele cobre bastante do conteudo que vc está buscando. Todos os assuntos tem exemplos e vc pode altera-los também pra uma melhor compreensão do assunto. Caso queira um conteúdo pago, indico o https://www.alura.com.br/ tem bastante material bacana lá.

Comment: Pó mano a principio achei muito interessante o site vai me ajudar muito, obrigado pela informação :)

Comment: @Leonardosfarias Todos profissionais experientes indicam ficar longe disso. É por isso que esse tipo de pergunta não é bem aceita aqui, sempre tem alguém que vai postar algo ruim como se fosse bom, porque a pessoa não sabe o que é bom ou ruim, só sabe que ela gosta daquilo, remetendo ao [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: @bigown entendo, oque você indicaria para meus estudos algo mais focado para programação.

Comment: Não gosto de fazer recomendações porque cada pessoa é diferente, e nem sempre eu tenho certeza da qualidade. Eu iria por um estudo estruturado, A praga da internet é que as pessoas acham que só porque tem um monte de informação disponível é só acompanhá-las que vai aprender. Até pode acontecer, mas é raro, quase a totalidade das pessoas que farão este caminho aprenderão tudo errado e vão achar que aprenderam certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela recomendação é que eu estou cursando Ads na faculdade e semestre que vem vou ter materias de javascript, como estou no começo estou aprendendo sobre html e tenho dois sites para estar criando, como sou iniciante estou sofrendo um poco mas estou me esforçando o máximo para fazer um site bem feito é fui recomendado por amigos tentar fazer parte de uma comunidade que iria me ajudar muito.

Comment: @Leonardosfarias estou aprendendo pelo curso em video, é mto bom. Segue o link: 
https://www.cursoemvideo.com/course/curso-de-html5/